# iPhone application deployment problem

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator, xcodebuild, ios-4.2

I'm a new iPhone developer.

I was made an iphone application and when i was finished i try to test on iphone devise

surly i have an apple certificate .,

i was loged in in my account in apple portal and follow the deploy hints ( i choose developing center in home page i pressed Lunch Assistant)

and i follow and apply all steps

BUt unfortunately when i was finished i tried to tun my application ..and one error occurs (this error occurs just when i try to test on Device )

i opened key-chain and locked at certificate and found written insted "The certificate is valid" i found "This certificate was singed by unknown authority" in red color.

i try many time and delete old keys and certificates and try operations again and in every time i facing same result.

if there any idea or solution try me ASAP

Thanks all

Adel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hay zebulon
thanx for pass

hi all.. simply i solved the problem by downloading WWDR intermediate certificat and double click on it..then the certificate convert to Vaild :)